# Why is react router re-rendering a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I click my navbar component whatever route I am currently on also re-renders. I'm not sure why this is happening. There are no props being passed to the route that are changing. Simplified code is below. I can provide more if needed.

```
const App = () => {
    const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => { setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen) };

    return (
        <Router>
            <NavBar handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} />
            ...
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={TimelinePage} />
                ...
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the NavBar click is changing the state, triggering an update on the App component itself, thus re-rendering all of its components.

What you should do is create a new component that handles its own state and contains the NavBar.

So it would be something like

```
<Router>
    <MyNavbarComponent />
    ...
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={TimelinePage} />
        ...
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

This way when you click the NavBar and trigger a state change, it will only change the state of your component instead of the App component and everything in it.

Just in case you want to know more about React and the update on its components, I highly suggest you read about its Lifecycle: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Hope this was useful to you.

Comment: Thanks John! I understood this for normal components but for some reason I was under the impression that React-Router worked differently. So obvious now that you say it!